# CodeContracts: Array access might be above the upper bound

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I'm getting these warnings from CodeContracts:

> Array access might be above the upper bound. Did you meant 0 instead of 1?
>   Array access might be above the upper bound. Did you meant 1 instead of 2?
>   Array access might be above the upper bound. Did you meant 2 instead of 3?
>   Array access might be above the upper bound. Did you meant 3 instead of 4?

On this line of code:

```
private readonly string[] _addr;

public string AddressLine1
{
    get
    {
        return _addr[0] ?? _addr[1] ?? _addr[2] ?? _addr[3];
    }
}

public string AddressLine2
{
    get
    {
        return _addr[1] ?? _addr[2] ?? _addr[3];
    }
}

public string AddressLine3
{
    get
    {
        return _addr[2] ?? _addr[3];
    }
}
```

How do I tell the Contracts analyzer that these indices are guaranteed inside bounds?  `_addr` is initialized in the constructor to `string[4]`.

Comment: Could you please show us where `AddressLine1` is being accessed and where in the constructor `_addr` is initialized?

Comment: Your code seems just a bit strange to me.  I'm just wondering why the lower indices are null but the higher ones might not be.

Comment: The reason its like that is we have two other properties just like it.  See my edit.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, because that's how we're getting them from another system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get rid of these warnings by adding a method to that class that defined the invariants:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void AddressInvariants()
{
    Contract.Invariant(_addr.Length == 4);
}
```

**However, I think there's also a bug in your code.**

If `_addr[0] == null` and `_addr[1] != null`, then `AddressLine1` and `AddressLine2` return the same value. This seems like a bug.

You can fix this easily enough (and remove the need to specify contract invariants) by using something along the lines of what @ryanyuyu mentioned:

```
public string AddressLine1
{
    get
    {
        // Use the first non-null element.
        return _addr.Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public string AddressLine2
{
    get
    {
        // Use the second non-null element.
        return _addr.Where(x => x != null).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public string AddressLine3
{
    get
    {
        // Use the third non-null element.
        return _addr.Where(x => x != null).Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, the invariant did it.

Answer (score 0):

`ContractInvariantMethod` works when _addr is a class member.  But `Contract.Assert()` works with local variables too.

```
static void MyParse(string foo)
{
    string[] split = foo.Split(',');
    Contract.Assert(split.Length == 4);

    string a = split[0];
    string b = split[1];
    string c = split[2];
    string d = split[3];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about the Contracts analyzer, but your code could be cleaner.  You are basically repeating code that just finds the first non-null string (and if the last element is null, you are returning that regardless).  I'm a fan of using LINQ [`.FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which will let you find the first element that matches a condition (in your case not null).  If no such element is found, it returns the default value (for a String it's `null`)

```
return _addr.FirstOrDefault(str => str != null);
```

See it in action at this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BQOyMg).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though.  Yes, I know I can use LINQ.  This question is specifically about Code Contracts.